# Copy checkbox from another workbook to current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying data from a template that has checkboxes, i'm not sure how to copy the checkboxes but i want to copy the data and the checkboxes into my workbook. I want the checkbox to stay exactly where it is in the template.

Here's my copying of the data though:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\myexcel.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks("copysheet.xlsm").Activate
Workbooks("copysheet.xlsm").Sheet("mysheet").Rows("1").select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("currentsheet.xlsm").Activate
Workbooks("copysheet.xlsm").Sheet("mycurrentsheet").Rows("1").select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: are the checkboxes ole or activeX

Comment: activeX checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying data should not be a problem, as far as copying checkboxes are concerned you can use below function

```
Private Sub CopyCheckBoxes()
  Dim fromSheet As Worksheet
  Dim toSheet As Worksheet
  Dim chk As CheckBox

  Set fromSheet = Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set toSheet = Workbooks("Book3").Worksheets("Sheet1")

  For Each Item In fromSheet.OLEObjects
    If Item.progID = "Forms.CheckBox.1" Then
      toSheet.OLEObjects.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=Item.Left, Top:=Item.Top, Width:=Item.Width, Height:=Item.Height).Select
      With Selection
        .Name = Item.Name
        .Object.Value = Item.Object.Value
        .Object.Caption = Item.Object.Caption
      End With
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you can't guarantee the checkbox to be in the exact location as the sheet copying from right?

Comment: when i used the above code, checkboxes were placed at exact places.